# running a while loop alongside jQuery without crashing the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a constantly running while loop to check alot of `if (value < otherValue || value === otherValue)` without making the website crash and still be able to accept click events, etc...
Here is some of my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var value = 0;
    var otherValue = 25;
    var otherValue2 = 75;
    var otherValue3 = 100;
    var otherValue4 = 125;
    var otherValue5 = 175;
    var otherValue6 = 200;
    var otherValue7 = 300;
    $('#button').click(function(){
        value += 5;
        // Here i make the value show on the page like fancy, but It's not essential for this question
    });
});
```

So, how do I include a constantly running while loop that makes that code still functional, and doesn't crash the website?

Comment: there is only one othervalue and one value then what do you want to use a loop for?

Comment: @Ankit I removed some stuff to make it shorter. There will be atleast 7 diffrent otherValues

Comment: @Ankit they are each individual differently named variables

Comment: Please increase your code in the question to make it a little bit clearer and running a loop seven times won't crash your site

Comment: @Ankit it's supposed to run constantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) it will allow you to execute a function every set amount of time.

```js
var interval = null;
var value = 0;
var otherValue = 25;
var intervalTimer = 100; // 100ms

$('input').val(value);

$('button').on('click', function(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        $('input').val(value += 5);
    }, intervalTimer);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
    
<button>
    Start Updating Value 
</button>
```

Comment: so, I created a function check. then added a line `setInterval(check(), 100);` but the code on the function doesn't seem to be running.

Comment: nevermind, fixed it like this: `checking = setInterval(check, 100);`
Thanks for telling me about that!